# Current directory ./ in qsub?

Tags: batch-jobs, working-directory

It seems that I cannot use `./` in `qsub` as in

```
qsub -q hpc-pool ./myScript.sh
```

where `myScript.sh` contains several `./`.

After checking,  `./` somewhat is translated to `~/`. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch jobs submitted by `qsub` are executed in your home directory by default.

[Some versions of `qsub` support the `-d` option to specify a different directory](https://wikis.nyu.edu/display/NYUHPC/Tutorial+-+Submitting+a+job+using+qsub#Tutorial-Submittingajobusingqsub-work_dir). To execute the script in the same directory where you ran `qsub`, use

```
qsub -d "$PWD" -q hpc-pool ./myScript.sh
```

If the `-d` option is not available, you can access the directory where you ran `qsub` in your script, in the `PBS_O_WORKDIR` variable. So add this line near the beginning of your script:

```
cd "$PBS_O_WORKDIR" || exit $?
```